# How to create a calendar and add an events using ios6?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, eventkit

I am working on universal App. In my App i need to add an event based calendar.

Is there any good tutorial to do this or anyone then please provide some information about how to create calendar and add an events to the dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at https://github.com/klazuka/Kal as its easy to understand and sample is also included.